# PCA - variables over 10 years for multiple assets

Tags: pca, normalization, dimensionality-reduction

I have 19 technical trading indicator variables over 10 years, for 25 different assets. I am attempting to reduce dimensionality to 2 components.

I want to plot all assets on a 2D graph against PC1 and PC2.

My questions are:

1. How do I achieve this, considering I have daily time series data? Surely, I must have only one observation per indicator per asset. Should I take the average of the daily data?
2. The indicators are a mix of prices and volumes. Many different ranges. Is it ok to normalise the entire dataset?

Comment: What makes you think that you need one observation per asset?

Comment: I can produce a variance covariance matrix using the timeseries data. 
However, when calculating the component scores, if i load all daily data for each asset, I will have a score for each day. Instead, I want just one score per asset.

Comment: In this example: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/53 , there are 329 countries, and 9 variables. Each variable for each country is represented by 1 number.

Comment: 329 countries, is that possible? Just to be sure I understood correctly: you have a certain number of daily series (25 ?), for a certain number of countries (19?) and you'd like to do some dimensionality reduction?

Answer (score 2):

About question 1.:

if you want to analyse the daily time series, then you should consider a functional principal component analysis (fPCA). fPCA generalises the usual PCA for handling functional data, i.e. datasets in which the statistical unit is not a single observation but a curve or a function. I believe there are several possible variants fPCA. The book by Ramsay et al. (2009) Functional Data Analysis with R and MATLAB edited by Springer, is a great reference. The book comes with a handy $\texttt{R}$ package called $\texttt{fda}$.

About question 2.:

In case of the functional data approach I'm not sure how do you perform the standardisation, you need to check the literature. But in the yearly averaged data, yes, standardisation is always a must in PCA.